# Problems with packages understanding

Tags: java, package, naming

I am making a game on java, so I need some help with it.
I want to organize my code in packages, but I don't understand which .java file belongs were. [My file organization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEWvO.png)

App.java

```
package main;
import engine.io.Window;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW;
public class App implements Runnable {
    public Thread game;
    public static Window window;
    public static final int WIDTH = 1280, HEIGHT = 760;
    public void start() {
        game = new Thread(this, "game");
        game.start();
    }
    public static void init() {
        window = new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Game");
        window.create();
    }
    public void run() {
        init();
        while (!window.shouldClose()) {
            update();
            render();
        } 
    }
    private void update() {
        window.update();
    }
    private void render() {
        window.swapBuffers();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new App().start();
    }
}
```

And Window.java

```
package engine.io;

import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWVidMode;

public class Window {
    private int width, height;
    private String title;
    private long window;
    public int frames;
    public static long time;

    public Window(int width, int height, String title) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void create() {
        if (!GLFW.glfwInit()) {
            System.err.println("ERROR: GLFW wasn't initializied");
            return;
        }

        window = GLFW.glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title, 0, 0);

        if (window == 0) {
            System.err.println("ERROR: Window wasn't created");
            return;
        }

        GLFWVidMode videoMode = GLFW.glfwGetVideoMode(GLFW.glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
        GLFW.glfwSetWindowPos(window, (videoMode.width() - width) / 2, (videoMode.height() - height) / 2);
        GLFW.glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);


        GLFW.glfwShowWindow(window);

        GLFW.glfwSwapInterval(1);

        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public void update() {
        GLFW.glfwPollEvents();
        frames++;
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() > time + 1000) {
            GLFW.glfwSetWindowTitle(window, title + " | FPS: " + frames);
            time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            frames = 0;
        }
    }

    public void swapBuffers() {
        GLFW.glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }

    public boolean shouldClose() {
        return GLFW.glfwWindowShouldClose(window);
    }
}
```

I get the following errors:
The declared package "main" does not match the expected package "ourRTS"
and
The import engine cannot be resolved.

Comment: I wouldn't name a package "main". I would have used the engine.io as the package. Do you have a domain name? Many people use an ip-name to keep their names to themselves, like 'package engine.foobar.com;'

Comment: Does your directory structure match the package names? I.e. is `App.java` in a folder named `main/` and `Window.java` in `engine/io/`, relatove to your project's root directory? What directory layout are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Consider one directory a 'default' or 'home' directory; whatever it is, its name does not have to be anything related to the project. It can be at the root of a disk or not, it can be many levels down from the root, its location that way does not matter.

The first name in each package (before the first period) in your application is a directory name off that 'default' directory. Successive names in each package (after each period) are levels of directories under the previous package name segment.

You have 'engine.io', so under your default directory you will have the directory "engine", and under that a directory named "io". All java files in package "engine.io" must be in the io directory.

Those are the directory and package names as they must exist in your java files and in the project. In eclipse, the default directory is often named "src", and sometimes the top-level package name directories are under that. I can't tell if yours is organized that way, but it's a common way to do it.

Comment: so in App.java it should be
"package ourRTS.src.main;"
Yes??? And for Window.java "package ourRTS.src.engine.io;" so?

Comment: Packages are typically all lower case.

Comment: @Slava_Yarmolenko I cannot tell what the package should be. You have a directory .../src/engine/engine.io (which cannot hold java files in packages, btw), and you have .../src/main/java/ourRTS. If you are going to put java files in the latter, then yes, the package would have to be (or end with) ourRTS, and that would work but break java naming conventions for lower-case package names. I think you mean /src/engine/io for the former, but then I don't know what your 'base' ('default', 'root') directory is - it should be the same for both the directories with sources.

Comment: I have put the screenshot of my folder structure in a link.

Comment: Yes, and I referred to it in my last comment. I don't know whether the 'root' directory for the packages is /src/ or /src/main/java.